# How to call shell from perl script

Tags: perl

Perl script reads url from config file. In config file data stored as URL=http://example.com.
How can I get site name only. I've tried

```
open(my $fh, "cut -d= -f2 'webreader.conf'");
```

But it doesn't work.

Please, help!

Comment: You're passing a shell command as a file path...

Comment: Personally, I'd say 'don't'. There's not many reasons to try and do something like a `cut` from within perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to indicate with reading pipe `-|` that what follows is command which gets forked,

```
open(my $fh, "-|", "cut -d= -f2 'webreader.conf'") or die $!;

print <$fh>; # print output from command
```

Better approach would be to read file directly by perl,

```
open( my $fh, "<", "webreader.conf" ) or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my @F = split /=/;
    print @F > 1 ? "$F[1]\n" : "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$ cat urls.txt 
URL=http://example.com
URL=http://example2.com
URL=http://exampleXXX.com

$ ./urls.pl 
http://example.com
http://example2.com
http://exampleXXX.com

$ cat urls.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file='urls.txt';
open(X, $file) or die("Could not open  file.");

while (<X>) { 
    chomp;
    s/URL=//g;
    print "$_\n"; 
}
close (X);
```

Comment: You don't report `$!` when dieing if file open fails, you don't do a three argument open see [perldoc open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), no `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Beside the issues mentioned by @Dr.Avalanche you should also use lexical filehandles.